# Using <<<CON in PHP

Tags: php, operators, heredoc

What is the effect of the following code?

```
$page = <<<CON
<p><center>Blah blah blah</center></p>
CON;
```

What does the `<<<CON` do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is known as [`heredoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). It's essentially a way of defining the value of a variable that spans multiple lines, and doesn't require escaping like traditional strings. The "CON" part is merely an identifier that represents the start and end of the value. This can be changed to a more familiar value.

```
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;
```

Comment: +1 Solid answer. One thing to note may be that the last line `EOD;` can not be indented afaik (making for some ugly code sometimes).

Comment: Correct, ChristopheD. Nothing before the last identifier, and nothing after (with the exception of the semi-colon).

Answer (score 2):

That's the PHP **heredoc** operator.  Details at this link:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc